# Vue Component Property or method "x" is not defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Got a problem that my component in vue is not working correctly.
I am kinda new to the typescript stuff so don't know alot about it.
Also in the vue debugger in Chrome it says it has two $attr: title and link.
Got two files at this moment.
The navigation:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">HBS2</router-link>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navContent" aria-controls="navContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=navContent>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <NavItem  v-for="menuItem in menuItems"
                v-bind:key="menuItem.id"
                v-bind:title="menuItem.title"
                v-bind:link="menuItem.link"
                />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
import NavItem from '@/components/common/main/navigation/NavItem.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    NavItem
  }
})
export default class Navigation extends Vue {
    menuItems = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'foo',
        link: '/foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'bar',
        link: '/bar'
      }
    ]
}
</script>
```

and the NavItem Component

```
<template>
    <li class="nav-item">
        {{title}}
    </li>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { Prop, Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class NavItem extends Vue {}
```

I also tried to create a Prop in the NavItem but also didn't work.

Edit:
The error message is as following:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <NavItem> at src/components/common/main/navigation/NavItem.vue
       <Navigation> at src/components/common/main/navigation/Navigation.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Comment: Could you please include the error message in the question? I assume the real error message does not say `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the type of your `menuitems` array set it in the `mounted()` life cycle method.

```
export default class Navigation extends Vue {
  menuItems : Array<{}>;

  // Lifecycle hook
  mounted () {
    menuItems = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'foo',
        link: '/foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'bar',
        link: '/bar'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The above didn't help and the error went from not knowing the title to not knowing the menuItems

Comment: Ok, and this in combination with removing the v-binds and use props again. I don't see why you are using v-bind.

Comment: Thanks it worked by making everything a Prop. Now i only need to fix the next: because apperently props may not directly be mutated.

Comment: @BGestel you should take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532260/vue-emitting-vs-passing-function-as-props