# Call parent methods from child components (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm doing a project and I need to call parent methods from child components. How can this be accomplished in Vue.js?

Comment: with `this.$emit()`

Comment: can you provide some more details please.link maybe

Comment: you emit an event somehwere in your child  with `this.$emit("myEvent")`. In your parent component lets say the name of the child is `myComponent` so you need to listen to that event with `<myComponent @myEvent="putYourParentMethodHere"></myComponent>` thats how it works

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Answer (score 22):

You should use `this.$emit('myEvent')` inside of your child component, when you want to trigger the method in the parent.

Then find your child component in the template of the parent and add an event catcher on it like this:

```
<template>
  <your-child-component @myEvent="myMethod"/>
</template>
```

If you want to add parameters to your method, you can add a second parameter to your emit like this:

```
this.$emit("myEvent", "My parameter")
```

For this to work you don't have to change anything in the event "catcher", as long as the method you call has a parameter.

Comment: Be careful with the casing of the event name. At least in vuejs3 mixed case is not supported in the component call, so:
<your-child-component @myEvent="myMethod"/>
should read:
<your-child-component @my-event="myMethod"/>

Answer (score 7):

[image: Props and Emit]

Maybe working example will make it more clear.

https://m-vue-leaflet.netlify.app/

code- https://github.com/manojkmishra/vue-leaflet-mapping

So here if you see there are 3 vue files in components folder.
Brew.vue is parent component to BrewList.vue child component.

Brew.vue- Parent Component

[image: Parent Component]

BrewList.vue - Child Component

[image: Child Component]

Child component BrewList.vue is using emit to send mouse-over-brew & mouse-leave-brew values to parent Brew.vue. Also, in case you are interested Brew.vue parent is sending brew prop to BrewList.vue child.

[image: Child emit to Parent]

As per docs-
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Answer (score 5):

### Dec, 2021 Update:

It works with **`$emit`**. The name of @***callTest*** in parent component must be same as the name of $emit('***callTest***') in child component.

**Parent Component**:

```html
<template>
  <Child
    @callTest="test" // Assign 'test' method to @callTest
  />
</template>

<script>
import Child from "../components/Child.vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Parent",

  components: {
    Child,
  },

  methods: {
    test() {
      alert("Test");
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

**Child Component**:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('callTest')">Click Me</button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
    
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Child",
});
</script>
```

Again, the name of @***callTest*** in parent component must be same as the name of $emit('***callTest***') in child component.

---

If you use **`$emit`** in **`script`** section, **`this`** is needed different from **`template`** section.

**Child Component**:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="message">Click Me</button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
    
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Child",
  methods: {
    message() {
      this.$emit('callTest') // 'this' is needed.
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

---

If **`test`** method has **`2 parameters`**, you need to call **`test`** method with **`2 arguments`** in child component like below.

**Parent Component**:

```html
<template>
  <Child
    @callTest="test" // Assign 'test' method to @callTest
  />
</template>

<script>
import Child from "../components/Child.vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Parent",

  omponents: {
    Child,
  },
        
  methods: {
    test(num1, num2) { // 'test' method has 2 parameters.
      alert(num1 + num2);
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

**Child Component**:

```html
<template>       // Call 'test' method with 2 arguments.                          
  <button @click="$emit('callTest', 3, 5)">Click Me</button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
        
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Child",
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, this is the right way to do so:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

On the other hand, I believe in your scenario (which I'm trying to assume cause it's not really clear), you can use this.$parent.methodName.

Keep in mind that the second suggestion is less clean. It should be used just in case of need.

Answer (score 3):

So basically, there are 2 ways to answer your question

1. Using **$emit**, with syntax is **@**
2. Passing **function as props**, with syntax is **:** The same as your example

If you based on Vue docs and a lot of other Vue tutorials, you will see that they encourage people to use **$emit** event **rather than** passing **function as props** (the way you are using). The docs you can read here.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-for-communication-between-vuejs-component--cms-32354
[vue, emitting vs passing function as props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532260/vue-emitting-vs-passing-function-as-props)

The reason is Vue philosophy is **passing props down, emitting events up**. Using **$emit** will help to mark the function triggered as a Vue event, and therefore you can use global event listener. This will also may help you to separate between **data flow logic** and **event flow logic**.

However, using function as props is not wrong, and in fact, it can be used to achieve the same result. In my preference, I use the 2nd way when I write a component that has a default function, and the function is only overridden when parents pass another one. This will help me avoid rewriting default functions many times.

For the rest of the other cases, I will use the 1st way $emit.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with props.passed the parent method through props to the child component. and accessed from the child component.

in child component

```
props: ["lesson","fetchLessons"],
```

and accessed props like this in child component

```
this.fetchLessons();
```

parent component

```
<InstructorLesson  v-for="(lesson,index) in getFechedLessons" :lesson="lesson" :fetchLessons = "fetchLessons" v-bind:key="index"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Parent**

```
<complited v-on:passData="fromChild" />

  methods: {
      fromChild(data) {
        if (data.methodCall) return this[data.methodCall]();
      }

      aFunction() {
        alert('function: a');
      }

      bFunction() {
        alert('function: b');
      }
  }
```

**Child**

```
<template>
   <div>
    <button @click="parentCall()">Call Parent Function
    </button>
   </div>
  </template>
  methods: {
      parentCall() {
        this.$emit("passData", {methodCall: 'aFunction' });
      }
  }
```